# difference between _var and self.var

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

With all this new ARC stuff (which does not fall under NDA…) coming out, it seems like the default for dealing with properties is to set the property without and ivar in the implementation file explicitly until you synthesize it with something like:

```
@synthesize var = _var;
```

What's the best practice to use in setting the variable?  I know the difference between `var` and `self.var` is that `self.var` is using dot notation and is using the var's setter method.

Is `_var` just the equivalent of setting it up within the header files like in the good ol' days?  Where did that practice of prefacing everything with an underscore come from?

Comment: Has Apple specifically said that ARC doesn't fall under NDA? The only public mention of it I see is on the starfield in one of the WWDC slides...

Comment: @BoltClock: It's on the public promotional pages for iOS 5 and the LLVM project has published lengthy documentation on it. The specifics of its use on Lion or iOS 5 might be under NDA, but the general idea of what it is and what it does is public information.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/

Also: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: And, for me, this seems like a semantic or preferential issue, not really about the technology behind it (which is awesome, by the way).

Comment: This post (http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2011-June/015588.html) explicitly states that "[ARC] can be discussed
publicly"

Comment: @Ben Lings: Sweet! I guess that means I can undelete my ARC question as well... and thanks for the retag. I was sure [arc] was already being used for geometry questions.

Comment: @Ben Lings, thanks for that.  It's a little ambiguous but I'm glad it's there in writing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_var` is just a different name for the instance variable (presumably so you don't accidentally access directly it when you meant to use an accessor). It doesn't have any special meaning in the language beyond just being a valid ivar name.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a `@property` like: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *var;`, Objective-C 2.0 and above automatically, as of 2012, `@synthesize`s that property to create three things:

- An underlying instance variable of `NSString *_var`.
- A method for getting the underlying instance variable: `-(NSString *)var {}`
- A method for setting the underlying instance variable: `-(void)setVar:(NSString *)newVar {}`

Generally, it is not good practice to directly access or set the underlying instance variable directly due to messing with KVO and bypassing side effects that might have been placed into either the getter or setter methods.